# Apply highlight to pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I get DataFrame by function pivot_table:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['labor costs],
                         index=['Division', 'Perfomer'],
                         columns=['completed on time'], aggfunc=[np.sum, len], margins=True, fill_value=0)
```

[image]
How can I highlight the row by condition: on schedule == 0 and overdue == 0 like table above?

I do:

```
def apply_colors(df_slice: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        styles_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_slice.index, columns=df_slice.columns)
        print('df_slice.index', df_slice.index)
        print('df_slice.columns', df_slice.columns)
        styles_df['Perfomer'] = np.select([
            # Condition 1
            df_slice['overdue'] == 0 & df_slice['on schedule'] == 0

        ], [
            # Color for Condition 1
            'background-color: silver',

        ])
        return styles_df

df2.style.apply(apply_colors, axis=None)
```

And get: KeyError: 'overdue'

```
#print('df_slice.columns', df_slice.columns) 
df_slice.columns MultiIndex([('sum', 'labor costs', 'on time'),
                ('sum', 'labor costs',       'on schedule'),
                ('sum', 'labor costs',       'overdue'),
                ('len', 'labor costs', 'on time'),
                ('len', 'labor costs',       'on schedule'),
                ('len', 'labor costs',       'overdue'),
               names=[None, None, 'completed on time'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parantheses with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one match, `default` parameter to [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for space if not matched masks, for repeat coloring is used [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
def apply_colors(df_slice: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

        # print('df_slice.index', df_slice.index)
        # print('df_slice.columns', df_slice.columns)

        arr = np.select([
            # Condition 1
            ((df_slice.xs('overdue', axis=1, level=2) == 0) & 
            (df_slice.xs('on schedule', axis=1, level=2) == 0)).any(axis=1)

        ], [
            # Color for Condition 1
            'background-color: silver',

        ], default='')

        return pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], df_slice.shape),
                            index=df_slice.index,
                            columns=df_slice.columns)
```

Comment: I get: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type for return pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(np.any(arr, axis=1)[:, None], x.shape),

Comment: Uresolved refernce 'x'

Comment: @irina_ikonn - solution changed and now tested, can you try?